# Can one use $e^n$ instead of $2^n$ in Cauchy condensation test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) is useful for testing the convergence of infinite series.  The test is stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) as follows: for a positive non-increasing sequence $f(n)$, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nf(2^n)$ converges.

I am wondering if $2^n$ can be replaced with $e^n$, where $e$ is the base of natural logarithm.  Thus, does the following statement hold: for a positive non-increasing sequence $f(n)$, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^nf(e^n)$ converges?  The reason I am wondering is because my $f(n)$ has lots of natural logs, and using $e^n$ instead of $2^n$ would be quite convenient.

Comment: $2^n$ gives positive integers, and $f$ is a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$. You cannot feed numbers that are not positive integers to $f$!

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like $[e^n]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the integral part?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff makes a good point. Perhaps if you lightly changed this to something like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^n f(\lceil e^n \rceil)$

Comment: something like this maybe is of interest  http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2304246?uid=3739864&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21103091833063

Comment: At any rate, I am pretty sure you can make Cauchy's argument with any integer base $r>1$ and group terms accordingly. It might be that $2^n$ is just a simple choice. Have you every read a proof of Cauchy's condensation test?

Comment: Hmmmmm...  all good points.  @clark The article you referenced is behind a pay-wall, however, this brings another thought: is there an integration version of Cauchy condensation test, i.e., is something like the following true: $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx<\infty \Leftrightarrow \int_0^\infty e^x f(e^x)dx<\infty$?

Comment: @M.B.M. this is $x= e^u$ substitution

Comment: Oh yes, d'uh, of course it is!  (didn't see it right away).  So, in my particular problem I think it might be more convenient to use the integral test followed by substitutions...  @PedroTamaroff: I just re-read the proof and it actually makes more sense to me now -- it's just a convenient "substitution".  Thank you all for help!

Comment: @M.B.M. Glad to help.

Comment: The sequence $f(n)$ should be assumed nonincreasing, i.e. $f(n+1) \le f(n)$, rather than nondecreasing, for the condensation test.

Comment: @coffeemath Just fixed that typo.